# creating a thread to capture the screen repeatedly

Tags: java, exception, jframe, bufferedimage

```
package demo;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ScreenCapturingThread extends Thread{
    public ScreenCapturingThread(Vector<BufferedImage> screenShots,
            int frameRate,
            Icon cursor,
            Rectangle recordingArea){
        this.screenShots = screenShots;
        this.frameRate = frameRate;
        this.cursor = cursor;
        this.recordingArea = recordingArea;

        try{
            bot = new Robot();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        calculateSleepTime();
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(keepCapturing == true){
            try{
                screenShots.add(takeScreenShot());
                sleep(sleepTime);

                keepCapturing = false; //take only one shot

                System.out.println("here");
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setSize(recordingArea.width,recordingArea.height);
                frame.getGraphics().drawImage(screenShots.firstElement(), 0, 0,frame);
                frame.repaint();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public BufferedImage takeScreenShot(){
        p = m.getPointerInfo();
        Point location = p.getLocation();
        image = bot.createScreenCapture(recordingArea);
        if(cursor!=null){
            Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(((ImageIcon)cursor).getImage(), location.x,location.y,null);
        }

        return image;
    }
    public void stopIt(){
        keepCapturing = false;
    }
    public void calculateSleepTime(){
        sleepTime = 1/frameRate;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<BufferedImage> bufferedImages = new Vector<>(100);
        int frameRate = 10;
        Icon cursor = (Icon) new ImageIcon("src/images/blackCursor.png");
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(1280,800);
        ScreenCapturingThread sc = new ScreenCapturingThread(bufferedImages,frameRate,cursor,r);

        sc.start();
    }
    Vector<BufferedImage> screenShots;
    int frameRate;
    long sleepTime;
    boolean keepCapturing = true;
    Icon cursor;
    Rectangle recordingArea;
    Robot bot;
    MouseInfo m;
    PointerInfo p;
    BufferedImage image;
}
```

### Explanation

I have designed thread to go along with my screen recorder but I decided to test it first. This is what it is supposed to do:

create a new thread object by passing the appropriate parameters

take **only one** screen shot (during this test only), store it in the vector and before the `run()` ends, draw this on the JFrame so I can see what has been captured.

### Problem

I keep getting a `NullPointerException` at

```
frame.getGraphics().drawImage(screenShots.firstElement(), 0, 0,frame);
```

I don't know what is going wrong.
If you could please find out the bug?

### Update:

[image]
**Now although the `NullPointerException` is gone, the frame is blank while it is not supposed to be**

#### Why?

Comment: Test to see if the first screenshot is null.

Comment: @Aaron checked, it is not null.

Comment: Are you sure you added line: `frame.getContentPane().add(l);`? If so - show the code after modification especially - showing the frame.

Comment: @Xeon u might wanna see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014728/the-image-gets-drawn-at-the-wrong-position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JFrame` will not provide you with any `Graphics` until it is shown.

If you want to draw before `JFrame` is shown you **never should** do like this:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setSize(recordingArea.width, recordingArea.height);
Graphics g = frame.getContentPane().getGraphics();
g.drawImage(screenShots.firstElement(), 0, 0, frame);
```

because as [Andrew Thompson has correctly written](http://pscode.org/guifaq.html#2.4):

> Do not use Component.getGraphics(). Instead, subclass and override the paint() (AWT), or paintComponent() (Swing) method.
>
> Component.getGraphics() simply can't work. Java uses a callback mechanism for drawing graphics. You are not supposed to "push" graphics information into a component using getGraphics(). Instead you are supposed to wait until Java calls your paint()/paintComponent() method. At that moment you are supposed to provide the Component with the drawings you would like to do.

instead you'll be better off doing something like below:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(recordingArea.width, recordingArea.height,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            Graphics g = img.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(screenShots.firstElement(), 0, 0, frame);
            JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
            frame.getContentPane().add(l);
```